# How to launch two programs in parallel using a bash script

Tags: bash

What I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd App && exp start
cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator ./emulator &
```

But this just starts exp. I want it to start exp open another bash terminal and launch the emulator there. Any tips?

Comment: Do you simply want to run both the programs parallel?

Comment: @AbhijitPritam Yes exactly

Comment: Is the real code really **exactly** what you gave here, with no command separator between the `cd` and the `./emulator`?

Comment: `(cd app && exec exp start) & (cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator && exec ./emulator) &` would do. The `exec`s aren't even strictly needed, just an efficiency optimization.

Comment: @vonhact, I have provided you an answer please try with that and let me know

Comment: Damn @CharlesDuffy (▀̿Ĺ̯▀̿ ̿)
I guess I would just use tmux.

Comment: BTW, generally speaking, instead of "did not work", it's helpful to describe **exactly** what happened instead. Got an error message? Show it. Got no error message? Program 2 didn't start until Program 1 exited? Say that. Etc.

Comment: @ArchNoob, ...the above is going to extremes to be careful -- `cd foo && bar`, for example, avoids running `bar` in the wrong directory if the `cd` fails; and the `exec`s consume the subshells by causing the `exp` or `emulator` commands to replace the subshell's PID in memory rather than being started as a sub-subprocess. Not necessarily always essential, but good habits to be in.

Comment: ...if the problem is that one of your programs halts because it's trying to read from the TTY, f/e, we'd need to *know* that before we can suggest putting `</dev/null` on its execution. No details provided in the question -> suboptimal answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:-

```
#!/bin/bash
cd App || exit
#better always put a full path like /home/App/
exp start &
cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator || exit
#better always put a full path 
./emulator &
```

if you want to wait till both the process finish put wait at the end of the script

Comment: I'd suggest `|| exit` on the `cd`s, so we fail explicitly rather than running programs in the wrong directory should they fail. (This is something that http://shellcheck.net/ will catch).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, are you asking me to put cd App || exit 1 ?

Comment: Or just `cd App || exit` -- the default exit status is `$?`, so `exit` alone will pass through whatever exit status `cd` had if it fails.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, yes that's an nice advice indeed. I have modified my answer based on your advice. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use for example [nohup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)
like:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd App 
nohup exp start > exp.log 2> exp.error.log &
cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator 
nohup ./emulator > emulator.log 2> emulator.error.log &
```

something like that

Comment: `nohup` is only needed if you want the program to keep running after its terminal is closed. It isn't needed to run two programs at once in general.

Comment: Moreover, **bash has built-in support** for disabling the HUP signal, so you don't actually need `nohup` *ever*. See `help disown`.

Comment: `./emulator >emulator.log 2>emulator.error.log </dev/null & disown` will do the same thing as `nohup` would here, without the inefficiency of using an unnecessary external program. Not that I see a reason to use `nohup` for the OP`s expressed use case at all.

Comment: (Oops, I should have specified `disown -h` to be nohup-equivalent).